# What is the sense of distance in the definition of SSSP Problem?

Tags: algorithms

I was studying about algorithms and came across the SSSP problem which stated:

Given connected weighted directed graph G(V,E) and a node S, find the shortest path from S to all nodes of the graph.

The distance of a path between 2 nodes is clear. It is the sum of the weights of the edges that make up the path.

But I don't understand **how to** define the distance between a node and **all** the other nodes.

Then I would like to clarify how the distance from a node to all other nodes is defined.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined by the function $d_s(x)=distance(s,x)$. Basically, its just the distance function where we fix the source node to be $s$.

Comment: So, the real definition must be:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Given connected weighted directed graph G(V,E) and a node S, find the shortest path from S to every node of the graph?

Comment: And isn't it the same as running the solution of the single pair shortest path problem with fixed initial source $S$ to $V_i$ with $i$ from $[2, |V|]$ (assuming $S$ is indexed with $1$)

Comment: For the first comment, yes: it is finding the shortest path between $s$ to every other node. For the second comment: it is a valid solution. But its running time will be much higher. Modern algorithms find the shortest paths for all nodes in $O(|E|+|V|\log(|V|))$

Comment: Thanks for your help!